# Validating CharField size in Django

Tags: django, django-models, django-validation

Using Django 1.8, I have:

```
class Book(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=20)
```

In a management command script, I am creating the objects. On my test environment, I use sqlite which does not throw an exception when the field size exceeds the max_length but on the production, a different db would throw an exception.
If there a way I can make it validate the length or is there a way I can retrieve the CharField length to do the validation myself in my test environment?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do [`book_obj.clean_fields()`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/models/instances/#django.db.models.Model.clean_fields) to validate all model fields. It will raise `ValidationError` on failure.

It also gets called from [`Model.full_clean()`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/models/instances/#django.db.models.Model.full_clean).

Generally, refer to [Validating objects](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/models/instances/#validating-objects).